Can I be a hindu if I eat meat?
Hindu texts speak strictly against meat eating. I have seen people eat meat and still classify them as Hindus;

ye tv anevaṁ-vido ’santaḥ
stabdhāḥ sad-abhimāninaḥ
paśūn druhyanti viśrabdhāḥ
pretya khādanti te ca tān
Those sinful persons who are ignorant of actual religious principles, yet consider themselves to be completely pious, without compunction commit violence against innocent animals who are fully trusting in them. In their next lives, such sinful persons will be eaten by the same creatures they have killed in this world.
Srimad Bhagavatam 11.5.4

So can a hindu actually be a hindu even while consuming meat??
I have seen preachers like Swami Vivekananda even suggesting eating meat.
So who is right??

Kshatriyas eat meat. Also the phrase "without compunction commit violence against innocent animals who are fully trusting in them" just refers to torturing animals under one's care (like pets) or beating animals that trust them (like those animals who regularly come to one's home to drink food, eat leaves, etc)

Worshippers of Lord Krishna or Vishnu don't consume meat. The verse which you've quoted is from Shrimad Bhagavatam which is a Sattvic scripture. There're some that consume meat but their worship is said to be worship in the mode of Rajas (passion) or Tamas (ignorance) and is not encouraged.

The shastric injunctions are absolute, universal laws/truths/principles. All sAttvika gunas are qualities that encompass higher principle/virtue of 'Integrity'(dharmA/balance). Integrity means irrespective of situations(time/space),forms(species), relations(attachments), self-interests, one sticks to the virtue or principle.
But, due to your current conditions, you may not be able follow sAttvik principles. This creates contradiction between beliefs/principles, actions and results. This will result in 'Cognitive Dissonance'. There are only ways to address this conflict: 1. To stick to the principle (non violence) or 2. Adjust the belief, that violence is acceptable under some conditions and make effort to change overtime. Change your principle or change your action.
https://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-05-21.html
Indians followed vedic tenets strictly - especially non-violence among all the six dharsanas including buddhism and Jainism. My take, all the 3 rungs of classes had upanayana/sacred thread [which symbolises unity among thought, word, action]. Chances they may not have consumed meat.
The idea of Satsang/community that have similar values would relieve people of guilt/regret and help them focus in their pursuing karma/activities and improve focus/exploration/perfection.
Edit:
There was a king named 'Uparichara Vasu' who was the father of Satyavati, Santanu's (Bhisma's Father) wife in the beginning of Mahabharata era.  When there is a dispute that arises between the devas and the sages about the interpretation of the term 'Aja' in a Vedic injunction that prescribed for a sacrificial offering, they decide to go to Uparichara Vasu for arbitration. The sages state that such a sacrifice must be performed using grains, and the devas insist that such a sacrifice must be performed using animals such as goats. The king rules in favour of the devas. "This shows that ancient Sages were Vegetarians".
The epic also describes a legend in which Uparichara Vasu commences an ashvamedha sacrifice, but orders that no animals be slain. Instead, he offers the products of the forests to the devas, who come to receive his offerings. Vishnu is so pleased by this act that he appears at the ritual site, but allows only the king to witness him. "This shows the King Uparichara Vasu himself was Vegetarian".

There is a research by Dr. D.N. Jha, devoted to the the answer to your question. Its summary is a book “The Myth of the Holy Cow”. With many references to Vedas and shastras he proves that Vedic Aryans were meat-eaters.
Vegetarianism is a later hindu tradition, rooted in buddhism,and Jain religion. After that the vegetarian diet was promoted by vaishnava acaryas.
But for example Sikhs eat meat — jatka. Are they Hindu? No doubt they are. So sectarian preferences towards meat are probably not an indication of being Hindu.
I will gladly accept downvoting from vegetarians as a token to sacrificial fire of eternal truth.
